# Change column data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have this column `EndDate` (date, null) which is in an empty table.

I am trying to change its type to `INT`, using the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE [Schema].[Table] 
    ALTER COLUMN [EndDate] INT NULL;
```

The real schema and table names were changed with 'schema' and 'table' for this example.

This is the error that I am getting:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 42
> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Does anyone have an idea why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: because you can't directly convert a `date` to an `int`

Comment: IF the table is empty - can't you just drop the column and recreate it with the `INT` datatype?? But also: ***WHY*** do you want to store a **date** as an  `INT` ?!?!? It makes **a lot more sense** to use `DATE` for a date .....

Comment: Why do you want to make a column called `EndDate` an `int`? If it's an `int` it's by definition *not* a date.

Comment: But he *said* it is empty <big innocent grin> :-)

Comment: *"I do confirm that this column is inside an empty table"* This, as I mentioned, the error won't occur, @lyubol . The error is happening because you have data in the column and `date` and `int` are completely different object types. But, like mentioned, seems like you'd be better off `DROP`ing the column and the adding a new column.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to begin with. If you really have data to represent `Date` values, then **I promise** the `Date` type really will be soooo much better than `int`.

Comment: Not all systems treat dates are DateTime in their raw form which may be more desirable depending on your needs. Purists may disagree, but its moot if the need to keep it in its raw form is a requirement. So if its like a unix epoch it would be represented by an integer, but its moot once the Epochalypse in 2038 hits anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You do indeed get this error with an empty table.

> Does anyone have an idea why is that?

Just an implementation detail. ATLER COLUMN checks the type conversion compatibility before it starts the process of actually converting the column data and discovers that there are no rows.